# trying to use use facebook-php-sdk library to retrive facebook posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to pull facebook posts onto my site so that I can save and display it in my own format. I am trying to use the facebook-php-sdk library, found on the Facebook Developer pages. I used the following code after I required the library:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'MY APP ID',
'secret' => 'MY APP SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
print_r($facebook);
print_r($user);
```

The print_r into $facebook showed me a full facebook object, so I know its being created properly.

```
 object(Facebook)#325 (9) { ["sharedSessionID":protected]=> NULL ["appId":protected]=> string(15) "[MYAPPID]" ["appSecret":protected]=> string(32) "[MYAPPSECRET]" ["user":protected]=> int(0) ["signedRequest":protected]=> NULL ["state":protected]=> NULL ["accessToken":protected]=> string(48) "[MYAPPID]|[MYAPPSECRET]" ["fileUploadSupport":protected]=> bool(false) ["trustForwarded":protected]=> bool(false) }
```

(I took my app id and app secret codes out of the quote above).

However, the print_r into $user displayed

```
int(0).
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing that you have to go through the login flow before you can get any user id … start readin’: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Answer (score 1):

“What am I missing here?” Authenticating the user. You’re calling `getUser()`, but until you authenticate, Facebook doesn’t know *which* user to get details for. I’m also unsure why you’ve missed it, as it’s the example on the GitHub repo for the PHP SDK.

Comment: I am reading the facebook-login documentation, but I am a little confused. Is it describing how to create an actual login button, or is there code which you can write to log into someone's account?

Comment: You make a login button/link, have the user click on it – and then redirect to or call the Facebook login dialog, where the user gives appropriate permissions to your app.

Comment: Is there anyway to work around that? I dont want any login buttons. I just want the anonomous user to visit my site and see a page where I have pulled and posted facebook data, in the format that I choose.

Comment: Depends on what kinds of post you want to display (from a page or user), and whether they are public resp restricted in some way.

Comment: A lot of people don’t have their walls visible by the public, so you need some form of manual login/authentication if you want to pull any useful Facebook data.

Comment: I am working for a client who wants his facebook data to displayed as I described. What would be entailed for them to make their wall visible? (I am not so familiar with Facebook, and not even sure what the term 'wall' refers to.). If they would, could we avoid the button?

Comment: If he wants his Facebook data displayed, then he has to give your app permission to use it. If Facebook profile data were publicly-available without any permission from the user, then any one could scrape it!

Comment: Isn't that what an access token is? Its giving specific permissions to another user and no one else. Once he gives the code, shouldn't it make sense that I embed it in the code somewhere to access his data?

Comment: Well if you have an access token, you can use it in the `setAccessToken` method. But that’ll only allow you to query what you’re allowed to; it won’t allow you to query Joe Public’s data when he visits your app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what this `getUser()` function is, but what you have to do is very very simple and you don't even have to use a huge library (I prefer to use what I can check easily, or what I have written, if I manage). It looks like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18536568/using-facebook-php-sdk-will-only-show-me-one-like/18537709#comment27268563_18537709), or the other way around. Anyhow, I am repeating it here too:

In order to get your feed, you have to use a token. To retrieve that token, make a cURL call to using this url `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET`

Let's say you got it already and you called it `$token`. Use that to get your feed.

```
$pageFeed  = someCURLfunction("https://graph.facebook.com/{$yourid}/feed?{$token}");
//you don't need a login. You have to get an auth token though

    $jsonStuff = json_decode($pageFeed); //it's a json object. You need to decode it

           foreach ($jsonStuff as $feed)
           { 
            //loop through it and
            // finish it here

            }
```