# Using facebook-php-sdk will only show me one 'like'

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This is a follow up post to [trying to use use facebook-php-sdk library to retrive facebook posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533184/trying-to-use-use-facebook-php-sdk-library-to-retrive-facebook-posts)

I am trying to pull all of my facebook posts so that I can display them on my site. This is my code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'APPID',
   'secret' => 'APPSECRET',
));

$pageId = 'MYID';   
//$pageProfile = $facebook->api($pageId);
$pageFeed = $facebook->api($pageId . '/feed');

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
dpm($pageFeed);
drupal_goto($loginUrl);
```

When I inspect the resulting array, I see only one element, and its one `like` on my facebook page. It ignores all posts and likes, even the ones I created after I called the `loginUrl`. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your feed, you have to use a token.
To retrieve that token, make a cURL call to using this url `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET`

Let's say you got it already and you called it `$token`.
Use that to get your feed.

```
 $pageFeed  = someCURLfunction("https://graph.facebook.com/{$yourid}/feed?{$token}");
  // this is what you had  $pageFeed = $facebook->api($pageId . '/feed');

    $jsonStuff = json_decode($pageFeed); //it's a json object. You need to decode it

           foreach ($jsonStuff as $feed)
           { 
            //loop through it and
            // finish it here

            }
```

This works for me. I hope it helps.

Comment: I looked through the json and didn't find my data.

Comment: if the json called "data" is empty, then your application doesn't have authorization for that (you need to use a valid access token, with an app that has requested that type of autorization). If it's something else, please let me know

Comment: data isn't empty, it has one element, and that is one of my facebook 'likes'

Comment: for the record: if this makes it any easier to understand my issue - instead of my facebook user page id, I used a public facebook page's id. Now I see all 24 of their posts. So, I'm just trying to figure out why mine doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the answer with my working code. Hope it resolves your issue.